# Changing datatypes on a MariaDB replica is failing

Tags: mariadb, replication, mariadb-10.6

would love your advice

I have two MariaDB RDS instances - one master, one is a replica using binlog replication using this function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-stored-proc-replicating.html#mysql_rds_set_external_master

binlog_format = ROW
slave_type_conversions = ALL_LOSSY, ALL_NON_LOSSY (initially i had it set to only ALL_NON_LOSSY, out of desperation i did both)

I am changing a number of columns in different tables from timestamp(6) to datetime(6) on my replica, but show slave status is showing the error:

Last_Error: Column 3 of table 'mytable.mycolumn' cannot be converted from type 'timestamp' to type 'datetime(6)'

Is there something else i'm missing? some other dependency, some parameter i forgot to set? This doc made it seem so straightforward https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-when-the-primary-and-replica-have-different-table-definitions/#row-based-replication

Both instances are on MariaDB 10.6.15

Comment: DATETIME and TIMESTAMP differ by timezone?  LOSSY applies to numbers only?

Answer (score 0):

Noted. I've written this up as a  bug report [MDEV-32805](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32805)